# Does there exist a method to place heredocs in an r script? (This simplifies embedding sql queries greatly)

Tags: r, heredoc

I was wondering if there would exist some package to place Heredocs within an R script. It is one of my favourite features of Ruby since it simplifies code readability greatly.

I know that one of the great improvements of r v4.0 is the support of raw strings, but unfortantely I have to stick to r version 3.6 for now and raw strings still don't support syntax highlighting like in Ruby.

https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/ruby-heredoc/ shows the Ruby equivalent of Heredocs where I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know of any equivalent of Heredocs.. For better readability, I usually write queries on separate .sql files and then read them in the R script with `file.path(path,sql_file) %>% readr::read_file(.)` and use `glue::glue()` when I need to dynamically escape a part of the string.

Comment: It might be a nice feature to have, but it doesn't exist formally, and I know of no hack to mimic its syntax.